# How to declare consts that can be reached by import?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constants

I created a component class called DataGrid and inside it I created a **const** that defines few elements:

```
const ResultTypes = {
    Email  : 1,
    Event  : 2,
    Contact: 3,
    File   : 4,
    Skype  : 5
}
```

To access it in the current **class**, or **.js file** I simple use this:

```
if (x === ResultTypes.Email)
```

Everything is working fine, however, I want use this **const** in another component/.js file, like this

```
import DataGrid from './DataGrid';

... 

if (y === ResultTypes.Email)
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: `export const ResultTypes`?

Comment: Did you do *any* research before posting here?

Comment: @JaredSmith I did, however I did something wrong. The solution described by ZekeDroid worked to me.

Comment: @Dan two of the top three google hits when I googled "export value javascript" both mentioned exactly how to do this. I was too lazy to look at any more results, nor was it necessary to answer the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the MDN documentation of `export` covers this in detail.

Comment: @JaredSmith the problem is that I was trying to search as "how to declare global consts javascript". The way you googled it give me the right answers. I tried to delete this question however I'll flag.

Comment: Ok @JaredSmith you're right, consider that I'm someone that is still learning. The way that I was thinking to find the solution was wrong.

Comment: @Dan don't necessarily worry about deleting, it will get closed and thats fine. Also don't worry about making mistakes: its part of the learning process. Don't take SO site maintenance personally :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you can export constants just as you do classes:

```
// file 'foo.js'
export const ResultTypes = {
    Email  : 1,
    Event  : 2,
    Contact: 3,
    File   : 4,
    Skype  : 5
}

// file 'bar.js'
import { ResultTypes } from './path/to/foo';
console.log(ResultTypes.email)
```